# How to Customized the new order template: Magento

Tags: email, magento, templates

I want to make some text changes in new order template of my Magento so where i can locate the Template file or where i can do this in the admin panel.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make changes in template from admin panel as below :

Go to `System` >> `Transactional emails` >> `Add new template`

Select now order email template and make changes and save it.

After that you need to assign your curstom email template.

For this Go to `System` >> `configuration` >> `Sales` >> `Sales emails` >>  Select your custom template there.

Comment: So in default we can find the template code here:
[Magento_install]app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales

Comment: yes and after making changes it will save as new template

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek Thanks...!

Comment: @Xabby can you please mark this post as the answer to your question? Thanks!